# Allow user access controller in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I use authencation in asp.net mvc4

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

when I'm not logged in, can not call functions registered in RegisterController. I try

```
 <location path="~/Register">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
   </location>
```

but is not.
How to solve?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <location path="Register">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="roles if any" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

try this this may work .. change the role if u got any that need access!!